# Import SVN history with large files that exceeds GitHub size limit

Tags: git, svn, github, large-files

I have a SVN repo that contains large files (130MB) that exceeds GitHub size limit. I have imported that SVN repo to a local git repo but i am not able push it to GitHub becouse of that size limit. When i try it to push GitHub warned me with the size limit and suggested to me to use Git Large File Storage. I have installed and eabled large file support for zip an rar files but i still not able to push it with same reason.

Do I have to enable large file support before fetching SVN repo or whatever i do if a file size exceeds max limit will GitHub reject it?

UPDATE:

I know how to use Git Large Files on a new repo but how can i use it when importing a SVN repo? Does following works:

```
git svn clone --no-metadata svn://hostname/path dest_dir-tmp
git lfs track "*.zip"
git lfs track "*.rar"
git lfs track "*.apk"
git lfs track "*.exe"
git svn fetch
```

I am asking this before trying it becouse this repo contains about 3500 commits and it is taking too much time to fetch it.

Comment: Can you try and clone the git svn cloned repo into a separate pure git repo, and register lfs directive only in that new clone, try and push from said new cloned git repo?

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, Git/Github is meant for versioning of files, and should not be used to store binary or compressed files, as they can not be versioned properly.
For example a small change to the content of a zip/rar file would cause the entire file to be changed.

My suggestion for github is to link it as an external dependency from elsewhere, and use a build/dependency management system like composer.phar, Phing, NPM, bower, gradle, maven, ivy, or Pip to handle those resources.
Using github to store the dependency configuration and/or hooks, that can then be used to retrieve the resources at build time.

https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#external-dependencies
https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

I had to learn my lesson on this one the hard way as well, when I was only able to recover portions of my stored zip files after months of daily commits, when attempting to create a branch from a specific commit. 
Sadly Git just isn't meant to keep track of binaries.

For more info on your specific issue:
https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/

> Once Git LFS is installed, you need to associate it with a large file
>   in your repository. [Learn More](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-git-large-file-storage/)

```
git rm --cached path/to/file.zip
git lfs track "*.zip"
git add path/to/file.zip
git commit -m"Staging file as committed"
git push origin master
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I do also know that Git not for binary files. I wish the people who developed my project first, had known that.

Comment: Ah, Git can't deal with small differences in binary files? And here I was thinking it was better than Subversion.